# What is the right way to assign/reassign a reference to an object in Python 2.x?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7 and I am trying to implement a node object that supports union find. Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, nodeID):
        self.nodeID = nodeID
        self.parent = self
        self.size = 1 

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<node nodeID: %d clusterID: %d clusterSize: %d>" 
                               % (self.nodeID, self.clusterID(), self.clusterSize())

   def union(self, other):
       '''someNode.union(otherNode) joins two nodes by attaching the parent of 
       the node with the smaller cluster size beneath the parent of the larger node.
       If nodes have equal cluster size, otherNode is joined below someNode'''

       selfLeader = self.find() #top node of self
       selfCID = selfLeader.nodeID 
       otherLeader = other.find() #top node of other
       otherCID = otherLeader.nodeID
       if (selfCID == otherCID):
            return
       elif (selfLeader.size <= otherLeader.size):
            otherLeader.size += selfLeader.size
            selfLeader.parent = otherLeader
       else:
            selfLeader.size += otherLeader.size
            otherLeader.parent = selfLeader
```

This doesn't work:-(

In case it's not clear, what I mean to do is initially create a node that holds a reference to its parent node, which initially is just itself (since it is the only node in the cluster). However, when I try to reassign self.parent in the union operation, I end up reassigning self. I'm pretty sure this is because of the way I am setting the reference in **init**:

```
self.parent = self
```

What is the right way to set (and reset) the reference to parent here?

Thanks!

# EDIT

It turns out I was hasty in posting the question. The assignment and reassignment is fine. I reported above that self was being reassigned when I assigned parent, which is just not true. I considered deleting the question, but I will leave it here for two reasons:

1) People have already taken the time to respond, which I truly appreciate.

2) I think the answer will be useful to the community, in that it provides a concise demonstration of object reference management in Python.

Comment: Downvote and no comment? If someone thinks it's a stupid question, how about some (hopefully constructive) feedback?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the init (and I do not know what is the exact problem!). I suggest to try some tests on isolated pieces of code...

Comment: I'm really stupid. The code works as it should, but I was doing the wrong test case. I suppose the downvote was justified (although a comment would have been helpful).

Comment: @Ampers4nd, you should post the full traceback, otherwise, we don't know what `This doesn't work:-(` means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with doing `self.parent = self`. Objects can easily have attributes that hold references to themselves with no issues at all. Consider the following test code:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None

    def setParent(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = self if not parent else parent

inst = Something()
print inst # prints <__main__.Something instance at 0xblah>
print inst.parent # prints None
inst.setParent()
print inst.parent # prints <__main__.Something instance at 0xblah>
inst.setParent(inst)
print inst.parent # prints <__main__.Something instance at 0xblah>
```

In that example, all the '0xblah' addresses would be the exact same. It's just the reference to the object that I created with Something's constructor and assigned to `inst`

Comment: This is right, of course. As in my comment above, I was not testing my code properly. Entirely my fault. Thanks for the answer.